# How to change the password reset email text google firebase

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the IOS library for my app. When calling the function

```
Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email)
```

I get an email that looks like this:

[image: reset email]

How can I change the subject header and text of this email? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any other code that creates the email itself?

Comment: no there isn't. at least not on the client side, but I have no idea what goes on behind the scenes on googles end @TimaGegewepe

Comment: I mean you are passing email object, how you are creating it?

Comment: it is just a string (email) @TimaGegewepe

Comment: not a duplicate? @frankvanpuffelen

Comment: can this be changed to RTL option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change email templates from Firebase dashboard (Console). Go to Authentication under Develop > Templates

Comment: awesome thank you so much! im suprised i couldnt find anything on this considering how simple it is